# Specifying which record to return from a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, mysql

**EDIT TO CLARIFY**

I am probably misunderstanding the use of `GROUP BY` so I'll just rephrase my question without making assumptions on how to solve the problem:

I have a list of `term_id`s and a table containing objects (which have an `object_id` PK and `term_id` as FK among other fields), I need to extract the object with the highest `object_id` for every `term_id` supplied. What's the correct way to do it?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out how to specify *which* record will be returned by a query with a `GROUP BY`. By default `GROUP BY` returns the first record in the group, who can I get the last one instead without using a subquery?

Basic query returns first record:

```
SELECT *
    FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (20, 21, 22)
    GROUP BY term_taxonomy_id
```

this works, but with a subquery

```
SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM wp_term_relationships
        WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (20, 21, 22)
        ORDER BY object_id DESC
    ) wtt
    GROUP BY term_taxonomy_id
```

this is a syntax error

```
SELECT * 
    FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (20, 21, 22)
    ORDER BY object_id DESC
    GROUP BY term_taxonomy_id
```

Comment: My TSQL head hurts at the thought of SELECT * with a GROUP BY actually working

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment as I'm not an expert in this area but my first reaction is that GROUP BY is about the group of records not a specific one. If you want to return the first row in a related set of records then TOP (1) and an appropriate WHERE clause seems more appropriate. If you are looking to return collected data from a group of rows, SUM, AVG, COUNT, etc. then use GROUP BY. If I've missed the point of your query then please elaborate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SELECT *... GROUP BY` is not supposed to work.  The fact that your first example works is a screwy feature of MySQL.

To make GROUP BY work, your SELECT clause can't be `*`.  It has to be a mixture of the GROUP BY columns and "aggregate" functions like `COUNT`, `SUM`, etc.

`SELECT COUNT(*), some_column FROM... GROUP BY some_column` is the expected form.

`SELECT *` is not expected to work.

You want to find the highest object_id for each term_id.

```
SELECT MAX(term_id), object_id FROM some_table GROUP BY object_id
```

Something like that?

Comment: Thanks I now understand how exactly to use GROUP BY, my bad for just skimming over the docs. Thanks for the solution too.

Answer (score 3):

Non of the examples you have posted are correct T-SQL. You cannot `SELECT *` when using a `GROUP BY` clause.

`GROUP BY` does not return the first record in the group - it aggregates by the columns specified in the clause (there are also the columns you can use in your `SELECT` clause).

You need to use a aggregate function (such as SUM or COUNT or MAX) in your `SELECT` clause. You did not specify what kind of aggregate you are trying to get, so I will use COUNT in my example, for the number of records:

```
SELECT COUNT(term_taxonomy_id)
FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (20, 21, 22)
GROUP BY term_taxonomy_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to repeat what the other answers say, but would like to add a little info on SQL grouping, which may help...

think about the query result being built in this order:

> **FROM** & **JOIN** determine & filter rows
>   **WHERE** more filters on those rows
>   **GROUP BY** combines those rows into groups (now one row per the group)
>   **HAVING** filters groups at a group level
>   **ORDER BY** arranges the remaining rows/groups

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` should be used with aggregate functions such as `count`, `sum`, `avg` etc. Such as:

```
 select product_name, sum(price) 
 from product_sales
 group by product_name
```